# WSO2 APIM - Retrieve Information about an API call in fault sequence

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Trying to get the API name in the fault sequence(ex: auth_failure_handler.xml).

Tested as below and it is not working,

```
<sequence name="_auth_failure_handler_" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
      <property name="error_message_type" value="application/xml"/> 
      <log level="custom">  
          <property name="ApiName" scope="transport" expression="$ctx:API_NAME"/> 
      </log>  
</sequence>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try with this:

```
<property name="ApiName" expression="$ctx:api.ut.api"/>
```

There are, some other useful properties, witch You can find on github:
[APIMgtGatewayConstants](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/APIMgtGatewayConstants.java#L22)